# Running an interactive shellscript using java

Tags: java, shell

I am writing a javacode to call a interactive shellscript and using process builder for calling shellscript. I know that to pass parameters to this shell script i have to take its inputstream to check it's output and need to use output stream to pass command to it. My question is that how would I know using Input Stream that it's  prompting for entering values ?

My code :

```
  ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder("/home/abhijeet/sample1.sh","--ip="+formobj.getUpFile().getFileName(),"--seqs="+seqs);

        script_exec = pb2.start();

                OutputStream in = script_exec.getOutputStream();

                InputStreamReader rd=new InputStreamReader(script_exec.getInputStream());   

                pb2.redirectError();

                BufferedReader reader1 =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(script_exec.getInputStream()));

                StringBuffer out=new StringBuffer();

                String output_line = "";    

                  while ((output_line = reader1.readLine())!= null) 
                  {
                           out=out.append(output_line+"/n");
                           System.out.println("val of output_line"+output_line);

                           //---> i need code here to check that whether script is prompting for taking input ,so i can pass it values using output stream

                  }
```

Is there any  way to know directly that script is waiting for an input from user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the process output stream and check for the input prompt, if you know the input prompt, then put the values to process inupt stream.
Otherwise you have no way to check.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
BufferedReader b1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter w1 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
String line = "";
String outp = "";
while ((line = b1.readLine()) != null) {
  if (line.equals("PLEASE INPUT THE VALUE:")) {
     // output to stream
     w1.write("42");
  }
  outp += line + "\n";
}

...
```

UPD: for your code it should be something like that

```
    ProcessBuilder pb2=new ProcessBuilder("/home/ahijeet/sample1.sh","--ip="+formobj.getUpFile().getFileName(),"--seqs="+seqs);

    script_exec = pb2.start();

            OutputStream in = script_exec.getOutputStream();

            InputStreamReader rd=new InputStreamReader(script_exec.getInputStream());   

            pb2.redirectError();

            BufferedReader reader1 =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(script_exec.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer out=new StringBuffer();

            String output_line = "";    

              while ((output_line = reader1.readLine())!= null) 
              {
                       out=out.append(output_line+"/n");
                       System.out.println("val of output_line"+output_line);

                       //---> i need code here to check that whether script is prompting for taking input ,so i can pass it values using output stream
                       if (output_line.equals("PLEASE INPUT THE VALUE:")) {
                           // output to stream
                           in.write("42");
                       }

              }
```

Comment: My question is same, that how would i check for input prompt ? I can set values using outputstream then.

Comment: You read the process output stream by-line, yes? When you read the next line you have to check this line for the key input sequence

Comment: i have added code with, can you tell me suggested code lines for that?

Comment: I thought of this solution. But i want to know this for my knowledge that is there any direct way to know that script is expecting a input from user?

Comment: I do not think that there a way to check this in general